# Node.js + jsdom + canvas

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas, dom, jsrender

Необходимо автоматизировать тестирование библиотеки на *JS*.
Среда для тестирования *Node.js* т.к. сборка проекта организована через *gulp*.
Сложность заключается в том, что нужно протестировать создание и работу блоков с **canvas**.

Задача, как казалась решается [jsdom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom). Возможность работы с DOM, почти как в браузере, появилась. Одно "*НО*": элемент **canvas** поддерживается на уровне *Element*, без всех необходимых расширений присущих **canvas**.

Например, ломается тут (на последней строке)

```
(function () {
    let dom = new JSDOM('<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="ru"><head><meta charset="utf-8"></head><body><div id="container"/></body></html>');

    if (!global.window) {
        let window = dom.window;
        global.window = window;
        global.document = window.document;
        global.navigator = window.navigator;
    }
})();

var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var context.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,150,0,0.75)';
```

Ошибка такая:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'fillStyle' of null
```

Ок, берем [canvas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas), который предоставляет необходимые возможности. И все бы супер, "*НО*" - этот пакет работает независимо от предыдущего...
Да, часть функционала с его помощью удастся протестировать, если подправить код проекта, но он нужен именно в связке с остальным DOM.

Нужна возможность после создания **canvas** в dom-дереве иметь возможность рисовать на нем, не вырывая из контекста.
Конечно результатом теста будет файл со сгеннерированным *html* и изображением с *canvas*, но в начале нужно что бы они вместе отработали...

Как подружить **[canvas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas)** с **[jsdom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom)** под **Node.js** ?

***UPD:***
Кстати, описание **[jsdom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom#canvas-support)** говорит о том, что он поддерживает **canvas**:

```
jsdom includes support for using the canvas or canvas-prebuilt package to extend any <canvas> elements with the canvas API.
```

Ну, типа, если вы подключили перед **[jsdom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom)** пакет работы с **canvas** (**[canvas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas)** или **canvas-prebuilt**), то будут вам полные штаны счастья (он подцепится и с ним можно будет работать как в браузере).

Возможно, что я накосячил при [ручной установке **canvas**](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/wiki/Installation---Windows) (*VS2017* не ставит этот пакет самостоятельно).
Буду признателен хотя бы и за ман по установке **canvas** под Windows.

Comment: DOM и Canvas никак не зависят друг от друга. Зачем вам тестировать их вместе? Тестируйте по отдельности.

Comment: Представьте, что вместо канваса у вас был бы флеш. Вам ведь не пришло бы в голову в такой ситуации тестировать флеш и DOM как нечто единое целое? Конечно, канвас и ДОМ входят в общую спецификацию HTML5, но всё равно это разные инструменты, нацеленные на разные задачи.

Comment: @Beast Winterwolf сложно коротко понятно объяснить зачем это нужно. Скажем так, создается что-то типа `<div><canvas><div><div/><div/></div></div></div>`, т.е. **canvas** с обвесом. Весь **canvas** протестировать полностью из *nodejs* не получится - многое контролируется только визуально. Но есть механизмы реакции **canvas** на действия в его окружении и наоборот. Вот их и нужно тестировать разработчикам, что бы не отломать ранее проверенное тестерами, что бы было меньше ручных проверок.

Comment: Оказывается не всегда тривиальная задача добавить поддержу **canvas** в **dom** под **node.js** в среде ***windows*** (под Linux, а конкретно под Ubuntu 16 LTS это намного проще...). Тем не менее, возможно кому-то поможет этот вопрос: [Integrating canvas into jsdom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46529039/integrating-canvas-into-jsdom)